Why can't my JWT token be validated after it has been created? .NET 8.0
I am generating JWT tokens in my .NET8 API for issuing on user login.
The logic that handles the token generation can seemingly generate a valid token when tested in jwt.io, however directly after generating the token I attempt to validate it using the same validation parameters that are contained within my program.cs class. and receive the following exception -

Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenInvalidIssuerException: IDX10211: Unable to validate issuer. The 'issuer' parameter is null or whitespace

It seems like the decoder is unable to find the iss: claim in my payload, although it is definetly present inside of jwt.io
Token code -
    var authConfig = new JwtConfig();
    _configuration.GetSection("JwtConfig").Bind(authConfig);

    var securityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(authConfig.Key));
    var credentials = new SigningCredentials(securityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
    var userClaims = new List<Claim>
    {
        new(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, input.Id.ToString()),
        new(ClaimTypes.Name, input.Name),
        new(ClaimTypes.Email, input.Email)
    };

    foreach (var role in input.Roles)
    {
        userClaims.Add(new(ClaimTypes.Role, role));
    }

    var tokenConfig = new JwtSecurityToken(
        issuer: authConfig.Issuer,
        audience: authConfig.Audience,
        claims: userClaims,
        expires: DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(authConfig.JwtTimeoutInMinutes),
        signingCredentials: credentials);

    var token = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(tokenConfig);

    // temporary testing
    var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
    var validation = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidIssuer = "https://localhost:7208",
        ValidAudience = "https://localhost:7208",
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("82551957-F31C-465F-895F-99DD9B40507C")),
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true
    };

    SecurityToken validatedToken;

    var test1 = handler.ReadJwtToken(token);

    var test = handler.ValidateToken(token, validation, out validatedToken);


Does the hardcoded key you have in the validation logic match the one coming from config? If so, this code should work fine.

@DavidG This turned out to be a package version mismatch, that manifested in a really strange way by only decoding some of the claims rather than all of them, so it seemed like it was mostly working while having fundamental problems that weren't visible to me.

I ended up getting to the bottom of this through much trial and error.
The issue seemingly lies in these two nuget packages having slightly different versions.

Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens  System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt

Once I made sure these shared the same version, my decoding began to work. It's quite strange how this manifests but hopefully this can help someone else in the future.
